# Play MP3 file from url backwards android

Tags: android, audio, mp3

I want to play an mp3 file backwards on Android. Currently my code streams it using a MediaPlayer. 
This is my code

```
MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
player.setDataSource(url);
player.prepare();
player.start();
```

As you can see now it's played forward. Is it possible to stream it backwards?

Comment: You could decode it to raw sound, reverse the buffer, and then play that reversed buffer.  There isn't a way to play an mp3 backwards natively.

Comment: How much time would it take? It has to be very fast

Comment: That is an arbitrary question, as it depends on the length of the audio file. No matter the length of the clip, you need to download the entire thing, reverse the waveform, then play that. You can not 'stream' it, as streaming will send the bits in the proper order.

Comment: @MattClark Can I reverse it with a php script and then stream the result?

Comment: All that accomplishes is more code in another place moving the workload somewhere else.

Comment: Depending on the size of the audio file, it should be a non-issue to flip it on device.

Comment: Will these clips be reused many times? If so, it may be better to do the reversal on your own server, and then serve up already flipped clips to your clients.

Comment: @MattClark those are hundreds of 30 seconds clips (about 400kb each) and my app picks many of them randomly so they won't be reused that much. The problem with my server is that I only have 10GB of traffic per month.